# PSD to HTML conversion

Tags: website-design, design-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pros/Cons of PSD mockups vs. HTML mockups](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/pros-cons-of-psd-mockups-vs-html-mockups)

I am a web developer. What happens is that the Client sends a PSD (Photoshop designs) to the company. Then the designer needs to create a HTML page from the PSDs

What happens every time is that the designer does not create the HTML with same fonts ie the boldness goes away and the font does not look similar as per the PSD means the quality is too degraded.

And the designer can convince my seniors that this is not possible i.e. The same font size, boldness cannot be achieved in the html while conversion

Can you please specify is it really true? or the designer is just fooling the developers.

Comment: Please don't cross post; moderators will move posts across sites if it's more fitting elsewhere. Your other post was moved to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/psd-to-html-conversion where it should get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question belongs to area of graphic design rather, but I will answer.

**Fonts**

There are some differences when rendering fonts both in various operating systems and in various browsers. In most cases a problem is incorrect use smoothing-mode of fonts in the psd.

Here's some rules the designer is obliged to know

[The Elements of Typographic Style Applied to the Web](http://webtypography.net/toc/)

[Fontsmoothing explained](http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/)

[OS X Quartz vs. Windows ClearType](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=1610)

Russian lng. / Preparing PSD to Customer-preview: Smooth, Sharp or None anti-aliasing.
[Part1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44657/)and 
[Part2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44693/)

In a static content use of non-web fonts as images (menu category or adv banner) is quite admissible, but, unfortunately it doesn't work for dynamically formed content, for example news title.

**Seamless textures & Patterns**

Many designers aren't familiar with the basic principles of HTML therefore choose incorrect methods at psd creation.
Create a pattern -> Fill background is a correct way, but not the opposite direction. In similar cases not always it is possible to allocate the pattern that leads to visual errors at fluid layout for example.

**Pixel perfect**

[Gr8 manual from Us2 also a PDF Available](http://www.ustwo.co.uk/blog/the-ustwo-pixel-perfect-precision-handbook/)

**Design etiquette**

[Photoshopetiquette](http://photoshopetiquette.com/)

PS 
Project dutys distribution will help to define responsible people for concrete stages of the project, but it rather belongs to category of project management.

In any case the knowledge of the HTML/CSS technologies and observance of above-mentioned rules by model preparation considerably simplify work.