# I create HTML mockups. How do I share them for collaboration?

Tags: wireframe, prototype, mockup, collaboration

When working with a client, I build several sets of HTML mockups. They range in fidelity, are responsive, sometimes have a bit of content, have a few animations etc. They usually come in batches - a set of linked screens that displays a user flow or a set of components. This part of my workflow is great.

But I also need to collaborate with client, so I then upload the mockups to a server and share a link to them to my client. After that, the client gives me feedback in meetings, calls, e-mails and so on. This approach has several shortcomings that I'd like to address:

1. Versioning is handled manually using folder names, i.e. is unreliable and a chore
2. There is no good way for the client to browse and compare versions
3. The client get no navigation or overview of their mockups
4. I have to add annotations, notes etc. as part of my HTML mockup (instead of related to the mockup version)
5. The feedback from the client is located in an e-mail or in my notebook rather than in direct correlation with the correct version of the actual mockup, visible to me and the client

I know that using e.g. InVision would solve my problem, but I'm not interested in using a wireframing tool (or JPEG-to-wireframe tool). I often use the mockups going into the implementation phase. They also gets me full control over fidelity, from a sketchy set of boxes to final front-end code if I want to. This makes the dialogue with the client easier - "Resize your browser window to see the tablet view". Another nifty thing about them is that I can pull in the client's current website's base layout, or a widget that correlates with the change. I'm simply not interested in using a wireframing tool. If InVision supported HTML mockups, however, my problem would be solved!

Comment: This is a great question for chat. I don't know if it's a good question for stackexchange as things get out of date very quickly.

Comment: As @mayo says, these questions aren't really suited to Stack Exchange sites, because there is no such thing as a correct answer. See this Stack Exchange blog post for more reasoning here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: See this related question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/pros-cons-of-psd-mockups-vs-html-mockups?rq=1. As it turns out handcraft is from [@Rahul](http://ux.stackexchange.com/users/249/rahul) who's one of the site moderators

Comment: @JonW Not sure I agree here, I'm not asking whether "X is better than Y". I'm asking if there is a way to improve a specific part of my workflow. There are possibly others out there using this or a similar workflow, that also would like to benefit from those improvements.

Comment: I've rewritten my post to focus on the workflow improvement

Comment: Voting to leave closed as still too broad. @Simeon, can you please edit to clarify what the key problems with the current workflow are?  And which of those problems (such as difficulty archiving old versions, difficulty communicating changes, or difficulty bridging between low-fidelity and high-fidelity versions) is the key one you're trying to improve at the moment?

Comment: @GrahamHerrli Better now? I've rewritten parts and expanded on the actual shortcomings of my current workflow that I need help with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't **one** tool but two - Dropbox and Github. Here's instructions of how somebody else set it up:

http://alexcican.com/post/guide-hosting-website-dropbox-github/

---

Edit:

Zurb's Notable feels like the best tool out there for collaborating on HTML mockups: http://www.zurb.com/notable

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While there is a possibility to add comments in Dropbox, the client would have to find the `index.html` (or other) file in order to add a comment on it. That's not the collaboration level I'm looking for. I want view-centric feedback management in direct relation to my mockups, preferably with the possibility to collaborate using comments (for discussion), notes (for documenting decisions) and annotations (for clarifying UX/UI details).

Comment: Ah I see. What about this: http://zurb.com/notable?

Comment: Amazing find, that platform looks exactly like what I need!

Comment: Would you edit your answer to suggest Notable? That way I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try any of these, they're not UX tools but they'll display your HTML well enough and all have versioning and sharing.

#### [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/)

> This is a simple viewer for code examples hosted on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

It's created by Mike Bostock and mostly used for showing [d3.js](https://d3js.org) pages. But essentially each page is just an HTML page with javascript - so you can use it to show your mockups. Then you can collaborate on the comments in the gist as well as the versions.

#### [CodePen](https://codepen.io/)

> Show off your latest creation and get feedback. Build a test case for that pesky bug. Find example design patterns and inspiration for your projects.

Finally there's always [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

**Update:**

As per comments - WordPress might work for a less technically minded client. WordPress [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) are just an HTML page with a PHP comment at the top giving the page a name. Then on the page you can have comments from the client by including the following PHP at the bottom of the page:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't see any collaboration features for bl.ocks.org, unfortunately. Regarding CodePen, it's a great tool for collaboration between developers! Unfortunately it doesn't have the collaboration features that I need when working with a code-clueless client.

Comment: How about setting up a WordPress site for it? Then you can create page templates that have the HTML and create a new page with the specific template. Add your client as a user with a plugin that informs them of updates. There is a versioning tool inside WordPress

Comment: There's a 5 star rated plugin for it too https://wordpress.org/plugins/mockup/ ((not that I've tried it)

Comment: For bl.ocks, you can collaborate via the comments in the Gist which has the versions too - but as you say this wouldn't work for a non technically minded client

Comment: I will check out the `mockup` plugin for WordPress. It looks interesting!

Answer (score 1):

http://notableapp.com provides some nice functionality for what your suggesting. It allows you to host entire code projects, have users comment and commit changes and even expands into usability testing.

Here's a better link - http://zurb.com/notable/features/code